# Python list value setting

Tags: python, list

I'm creating a program where an input object is checked to see if it is present in a list.  If it is then it gets the position number and then uses that to determine the response from another list.
Is it possible to have variables in a list like so:

```
list[1] = "Some text"
list[2] = "Some more text"
list[3] = "Even more text"
```

So that one very long list isn't needed (it also makes it easier to find term values)

If you are aware with arrays in Small Basic, you'll know what I mean.

Comment: Please don't call a list `list` because you mask the function by that name.

Comment: Sounds more like you want a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Comment: I think you should give a basic [Python Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/) a go first.

Comment: @SLawson I think you are right.

Comment: It seems I was hunting for the dict object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a Python [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), you can do something along these lines.

First, have all you lines of text in a multiline block:

```
constants='''\
Some text
Some more text
Even more text'''
```

Then use a dict comprehension to create a mapping betweens the lines of text and a number:

```
to_test={line:i for i, line in enumerate(constants.splitlines(), 1)}

>>> to_test
{'Some more text': 2, 'Some text': 1, 'Even more text': 3}
```

Then you test membership of some test:

```
>>> 'Some text' in to_test
True
```

And find the associated integer with the text:

```
>>> to_test['Some text']
1
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to dawg's answer, if you really want a python list, you should do it as such:

```
l = ["Some text", "Some more text", "Even more text"]
```

Then, you can use it:

```
>>> "Some text" in l
True
>>> l.index("Some text")
0
```

You could also build `l` this way, but it is less "pythonic":

```
l = []
l.insert(0, "Some text")
l.insert(1, "Some more text")
l.insert(2, "Some more text")
```

Also remember that python indexing is `0` based!